# PySpark Dataframe : comma to dot

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have imported data using comma in float numbers and I am wondering how can I 'convert' comma into dot. I am using pyspark dataframe so I tried this :

```
commaToDot = udf(lambda x : str(x).replace(',', '.'), FloatType())

myData.withColumn('area',commaToDot(myData.area))
```

And it definitely does not work.
So can we replace directly it in dataframe from spark or should we switch in numpy type or something else ?

Thanks !

Comment: How did you "import" data?

Comment: In Zeppelin, I use this line to import my data. My data are in a csv file in hadoop :

    myData = spark.read.option("delimiter",";").option("header","true").csv(server + '/user/hadoop/dataAirpl/C6H5_C2H3/C6H5_C2H3_2016_08_01.csv').

I also tried to find the list of the reader options in pyspark.sql.readwriter.DataFrameReader.option(key, value) without success.Here is the [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/readwriter.html) of the doc

Comment: The udf doesnt work because return type of function is `FloatType` but you are not doing string to float conversion. May be try like `lambda x: float(str(x).replace(',', '.'))`

Comment: Your solution does not work, but you are right : FloatType() does not exist.
The udf do nothing : the data is still the same with his comma.
Maybe he tries to find a line with this value : ',' and he does not find obviously...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
```

As Pushkr  suggested udf with replace will give you back string column if you don't convert result to float

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("ReadCSV")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlctx.read.option("delimiter", ";").load("test.csv", format="csv")
df.show()
commaToDot = udf(lambda x : float(str(x).replace(',', '.')), FloatType())
df2=df.withColumn('area',commaToDot(df._c0))
df2.printSchema()
df2.show()
```

I used single column file , tested on spark 2.11/python 3.6

Answer (score 16):

Another way to do it (without using UDFs) is:

```
myData = myData.withColumn('area', regexp_replace('area', ',', '.').cast('float'))
```

Comment: This is better than using udf IMO

Comment: This also bypasses the problem of casting NaN to string in the udf in zlidime's answer

Comment: I tested similar code by measuring the time and compared it with the `UDF` code provided by zlidime. I can confirm that `UDF` code is slower. I tried simulations on various datsasets and everytime `UDF` was slower.